# How to integrate a query into blade template in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, logic

I am trying to integrate my query into my blade template i want to show only those codes which has not been ordered but i am getting all the codes from the database

My blade template code:

```
<p>{{optional($value->coupon)->code}}
```

Here coupon is relationship and code is value i am getting but i am getting all the coupon here i want only those code which has been not ordered
I have made query in which i can get code which has not been ordered

My query is:

```
 DB::table('page_coupon')->where('is_ordered','N')->pluck('code');
```

but my question here is how can i add this query into my blade and my blade is running under foreach loop.

This is my model:

```
  class PageList extends Model
   {
  protected $table = 'page_master';


protected $fillable = ['business_id', 'page_url', 'page_name'];

public function particulars()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Sale','user_id','business_id');
}
public function coupon()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\PageCoupon','page_id','business_id');
   }

     }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: What does the `code` attribute need to return?

Comment: its need to return only that code which is not ordered yet as i mention on query is_ordered = N but i am getting all the code which is in database i have successfully made query to return only record which has not been ordered but i am confused how to implement in my blade view.

Comment: Please elaborate your question more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This If I have understand your question:

in your `PageList` Model:

```
public function coupon()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\PageCoupon','page_id','business_id')->where('is_ordered','N');
   }
```